# How can I link to bower components in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, bower, laravel-blade

I'm using bower to install some dependencies. The only issue I have is trying to load them globally throughout my views.

I'm trying to do this:

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('node_modules/sweetalert/dist/weetalert.css') }}">
```

Which results in:

```
<script src="http://project.dev/bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://project.dev/node_modules/sweetalert/dist/weetalert.css">
```

Which is obviously wrong because it's outside the `app` directory. How can I reference the libraries properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<script>` and `<link>` tags can only include files that are publicly accessible, i.e. inside the `public` folder.

Since bower and npm by default install these components outside of the `public` folder that means you have to copy the ones you need into `public`.

You can do this with your gulp file:

```
var bower_path = './bower_components';
var js_path = 'public/js';

mix.copy(bower_path + '/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js', js_path);
```

Run `gulp` and then include in your view with

```
{{ asset("js/sweetalert-dev.js") }}
```

(Copy the minified version if it's available)

You can also create a `.bowerrc` file inside your top level folder to specify that all bower components should be installed inside `public` instead of `bower_components`

```
{
  "directory": "public/bower"
}
```

I don't recommend this though because that exposes a lot of files to the public (that other people could hotlink and suck your bandwidth, for example)

Comment: Thank you for that Andrew, that's really helpful. Do I need to set up these `mix.copy` things every time I install a bower component?

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes, unfortunately. It's a little tedious. There's a package called `bower-installer` which is supposed to automate it but it relies on each component to be configured in a certain way and in my experience I ended up having to do more than 1/2 of them manually anyway

Comment: Alrighty no problem, i'll get used to doing this! haha. Thank you very much, really helpful :)

Comment: well said, helped me :)